# Android unable to pick multiple image from gallery in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have tried to pick multiple images from gallery, but its is okay upto lollipop but cannot pick more than one image in marshmallow even i got permission.

**Tried Code**

```
    private final int PHOTOS_GALLERY_CODE =2;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 5);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PHOTOS_GALLERY_CODE);
    }
```

Comment: Add `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

Comment: Your `Intent` has no action string. I am surprised that it works for anything.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is my code snippet is valid in his case along with the parameters that he missing in new Intent().

Comment: @W4R10CK: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, by default, only requests a single item. You need to add `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` to request that the user can choose multiple items, and not every `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementation will honor `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`.